# Let $(X, M, \mu )$ be a space with measure. $f:X \to \mathbb R \text{ and } f\in L^1(X).$ ..

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, M, \mu )$ be a space with measure. $f:X \to \mathbb R \text{ and }  f\in L^1(X).$ Prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$ that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for $E \in M$, $\mu(E)< \delta$ the following is true: $$|\int_E f d\mu|< \epsilon.$$ $(M)- \text{ is the sigma algebra assigned to this space.}$

This seems intuitively close to the notion of continuity. I know that if $f$ is a measurable function that $$\lambda(E)=\int_{E}fd\mu$$. $f$ is continuous, therefore measurable, I feel like I can use this, but don't know how.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct statement? Trivially for $E=\emptyset$ it is true.

Comment: I think the OP means "for *all* $E\in M$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$."

Comment: You are right with the continuity, this property is called "absolute continuity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $E_n = \{ x : |f(x)| \geq n \}$.  Since $f \in L^1$, $\mu(\{ x : |f(x)| = \infty \} ) = 0$.  Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n} |f| d\mu = 0.
$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then there exists $N \geq 1$ such that 
$$
\int_{E_N} |f| d\mu < \epsilon/2.
$$
Choose $\delta = \epsilon/(2N)$.  Then if $E \in M$ and $\mu(E) < \delta$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_E |f| d\mu &= \int_{E \cap E_N} |f| d\mu + \int_{E \cap E_N^c} |f| d\mu \\
&\leq \int_{E_N} |f| d\mu + \int_{E \cap E_N^c} N d\mu \\
&< \epsilon/2 + N \mu(E \cap E_N^c) \\
&\leq \epsilon/2 + N \delta \\
&< \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon. 
\end{align*}